# jQPlot Date On X axis Tick Interval Isn't Working

Tags: javascript, php, date, jqplot

Refer to the attached image. Date strings from php in format Y-m-d are plotted on the x axis. But as you can see the more dates there are the more quashed up it is. I wanted to use the tickInterval property of jqplot but it just isn't working!

It ignores the interval entirely and just plots each and every day there is. So if i have 1000 days it becomes complete unreadable.

[image]

```
var plot1 = $.jqplot("analyse-bottom-left",[yValues],{
            highlighter: { show: true, tooltipAxes: 'both' },
            seriesDefaults:{
                //renderer:$.jqplot.BarRenderer,
                rendererOptions: {fillToZero: true},


            },
            axesDefaults:{
                tickRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer,

            },
            legend: {
                show: true,
                placement: 'outsideGrid'
            },
            //series:seriesNames,
            axes:{
                xaxis:{
                    renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
                    rendererOptions: { tickRenderer: $.jqplot.dateAxisRenderer },
                    ticks:xValues,
                    tickOptions:{
                        angle:30,
                        formatString:'Y-m-d'
                    },
                    tickInterval:'2 days'

                },
                yaxis:{

                    tickOptions: {formatString: '£%d'}
                }

            }    
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `xaxis` options aren't valid. You have set it as `CategoryAxisRenderer` and then try to set the ticks as `DateAxisRenderer`.  This won't work because the axis itself needs to use `DateAxisRenderer`.

Try this:

```
xaxis:{
    renderer: $.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,
    ticks: xValues,
    tickOptions:{
        angle: 30,
        formatString: '%Y-%m-%d'
    },
    tickInterval: '2 days',
    min: xValues[0]
}
```

---

I have created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/atu8fggw/) to demonstrate the usage. jqPlot has many quirks - in this case to make tickInterval work you must specify the 'min' value.

Comment: Ignore the image i put dateAxisRenderer not DateAxisRenderer. However, nothing has changed, the intervals are still 1 day not 2

Comment: Please don't edit an answer to reply to the author. Either add a comment or edit your question.

Comment: it's not plotting the Y values anymore either...strange. I added some x and y values manually and nothing on the graph. If i use CategroyAxisRenderer it works fine...

Comment: You can edit answers to _improve_ them, not to state that they don't work. I'm testing your code now...

Comment: @NibbrWebDevelopment Please see the update to my answer and check the jsfiddle.